# Multi-Dimensional arrays in php - having two arrays with the same name?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

Basically building a SOAP Client, and part of the required input is formatted as so:

```
<Attributes>
    <Attribute>
         <AttributeType>HomeType</AttributeType>
         <Value>duplex</Value>
    </Attribute>
    <Attribute>
        <AttributeType>Bedrooms</AttributeType>
        <Value>2</Value>
    </Attribute>
    <Attribute>
        <AttributeType>Bathrooms</AttributeType>
        <Value>2</Value>
    </Attribute>
</Attributes>
```

This is posted via an Array:

```
$homeType = array (

'AttributeType' => 'HomeType',
'Value' => $_POST['hometype']
);
$bedrooms = array (
'AttributeType' => 'Bedrooms',
'Value' => $_POST['bedrooms']
);
$bathrooms = array(
'AttributeType' => 'Bathrooms',
'Value' => $_POST['bathrooms']
);
$attributes = array (
'Attribute' => $homeType,
'Attribute' => $bedrooms,
'Attribute' => $bathrooms
);
```

And as you can imagine, all the Array returns is the last attribute, so the xml looks like:

```
<Attributes>
    <Attribute>
        <AttributeType>Bathrooms</AttributeType>
        <Value>2</Value>
    </Attribute>
</Attributes>
```

I can't think of any practical way around this, as the Attributes can count up to 30-50, so I don't want to numerically key them, especially as the array is only called as:

```
'Attributes' => $attributes,
```

Any help would be massively appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shouldn't you just use an array?
$attributes = array(
  'Attribute' => array($homeType, $bedrooms, $bathrooms)
);

Comment: If that happens the output would only be:
<Attributes>
    <Attribute>
         <AttributeType>HomeType</AttributeType>
         <Value>duplex</Value>
        <AttributeType>Bedrooms</AttributeType>
        <Value>2</Value>
        <AttributeType>Bathrooms</AttributeType>
        <Value>2</Value>
    </Attribute>
</Attributes> - meaning the SOAP call would break

Comment: Sorry Stefan, I take that all back! For some reason that worked perfectly, the SOAP Server must automatically put each array into the XML parent. Also, even though the questions answered - the SOAP Server generates the XML, the call is done through PHP5's SOAP Client service! Cheers again, I never would of thought of that.

Comment: You're most welcome :) Feel more than welcome to mark this an answer as well, cheers!

Comment: Waiting for the silly time limit! Shall do in approximately two mins ;)